# Python GUI using tkinter and db connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am not able to get any output from the following program.What i am trying to do here is store employee name and salary in a database and later delete database entries based on name and id.It gives no error. I think its a database error. it is not inserting any values in the db . Please help. Thanks

```
import Tkinter
import sqlite3
import ttk


def put(*args):
    try:
        e_name = str(i_name)
        e_pay = int(i_pay)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('medha.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('create table if not exists employee(id integer primary key auto increment, name text, salary integer)')
        c.execute('insert into employee(name, salary) values(?,?)',(e_name,e_pay))
        conn.close()
        notice = 'insertion successful'
    except:
        notice ='insert proper values'

def del_id(*args):
    try:
        e_id = int(d_del)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('medha.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('delete from employee where id =?',(e_id))
        notice = 'deleted successfully'
        conn.close()
    except:
        notice = 'insert proper values'

def del_name(*args):
    try:
        e_name = int(d_del)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('medha.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('delete from employee where name = ?',(e_name))
        notice = 'deleted successfully'
        conn.close()
    except:
        notice = 'insert proper values'

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Python Projet - gui and db')

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root,padding='3 3 12 12' )
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight =1)

i_name = str()
i_id = str()
i_pay = str()
notice = str()
d_del = str()

i_name_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width =7, textvariable = i_name)
i_name_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

i_id_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width =7, textvariable = i_id)
i_id_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

i_pay_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width =7, textvariable = i_pay)
i_pay_entry.grid(column = 3, row = 1)

i_del_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width =7, textvariable = d_del)
i_del_entry.grid(column = 1, row =4)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='Name of Employee').grid(column = 1, row = 0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='Employee ID').grid(column = 2, row =0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='Employee Pay').grid(column = 3, row=0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='Name/ID of Employee to delete').grid(column = 1, row=3)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = notice).grid(column = 1, row = 6)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Insert', command = put).grid(column=3, row=2)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Delete By ID', command = del_id).grid(column =1, row = 5)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Delete By Name', command = del_name).grid(column = 3, row=5)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5,pady=5)
i_name_entry.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "store employee name and salary in a database and later delete database entries based on name and id" - what part of what you described is not working?

Comment: I am able to get the GUI, but on clicking the button the put() function does not work.. even database is not created.

Comment: If you suspect an error is occurring, it may be useful to remove your try-except blocks, since they prevent any stack traces from being printed to the console.

Comment: @Kevin your idea worked.. got the error.. says invalid literal for int with base 10.. this happens when i am converting text from input field to integer e_pay = int(i_pay)

Comment: Ah, that's because `i_pay` always keeps the value `""`, since it doesn't update when the user types in `i_pay_entry`. You could make `i_pay` a StringVar too, and do `e_pay = int(i_pay.get())`. And similar for all your other str() variables.

Comment: my lappy crashed.. will do that and get back to u. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = notice).grid(column = 1, row = 6)
```

Changing the value of the string `notice` won't update the text in this label. You need to use a [StringVar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for this.

```
notice = Tkinter.StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = notice).grid(column = 1, row = 6)
```

Then, instead of doing `notice = "whatever"` in your functions, do `notice.set("whatever")`.

---

Alternatively, don't have a `notice` value at all. Just reconfig the text variable directly.

```
notice_label = ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "")
notice_label.grid(column = 1, row = 6)
```

(note: don't try to assign `notice_label` and do `grid` on the same line, it won't work)

Then do `notice_label.config(text = "whatever")` instead of `notice = "whatever"`.

Comment: it says StringVar() not defined. Do i have to import anything to make it work.

Comment: `StringVar` belongs to the `Tkinter` module, so you may need to do `notice = Tkinter.StringVar()`.

Comment: using Tkinter.StringVar() worked for me..but code is still not working.. on button click it still does not execute the put() function

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `put` is not being called? if you put `print "put is being called"` as the first line of the `put` function, will that value be printed? I tried and it works on my machine.

Comment: values are not getting into database..as in it says values inserted but nothing is present inside db

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there. I know a lot about Tkinter, but nothing about sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

First try to see if you are connected to your database. With postgreSQL you can connect via psycopg2

```
import psycopg2

try:    
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="user", user="postgres", password="silverTip", host="localhost")
        print("connected")
    except:
        print ("I am unable to connect to the database")
    cur =conn.cursor()
```

so if you are connected to database, it will print connected,
else you will get message unable to connect to database